# Create pivot-like table/chart in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities

I have some data that looks like this:

| a | b | c | group | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 124 | 43 | aa | 01/02/2023 |
| 25 | 235 | 648 | bb | 05/01/2023 |
| 863 | 93 | 523 | cc | 10/11/2023 |
| 423 | 263 | 367 | aa | 06/08/2023 |
| 83 | 75 | 33 | cc | 22/04/2023 |

I want to create some pivot-style charts in Salesfroce.

One chart should be a stacked bar chart or donut chart with the sum(a,b,c) and split by the total amount of each of the 3 variables.

Another chart should be the total sum(a,b,c) but grouped by 'group'. Basically, i would want to groupBy('group') and sum(a,b,c).

And i would want to insert these 2 charts in a dashboard. Do i need to create 2 different reports on Salesforce to do this? I have tried to make some pivot equivalent but i couldn't find a way. I can group by the 'group' variable, but when i try to add a donut chart, it only shows the total for one variable, rather than all 3 at the same time